# plugin.xml is missing in Android

Tags: java, android, cordova

I want to create phone gap app in android.I have add cordova-2.0.0.jar file added in libs folder and build the path also and give the permission in Menifest file also.When i run the app the log cat says plugin.xml is missing.can someone give me idea here how to implement phone gap .Thanks to appreciate.

Here is my Button code

```
public class Start_Screen extends DroidGap
{
    Button btnLearn;
    Button btnExam;

    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.starting_screen);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);

        btnExam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExam);
        btnExam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/message.html");
            }
        });
        }
}
```

Here is log cat info
09-22 15:47:47.602: E/PluginManager(1339): ERROR: plugin.xml is missing.  Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your project.
09-22 15:47:47.602: E/PluginManager(1339): https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/res/xml/plugins.xml

Answer (score 0):

use this code in MainActivity.java  file

```
 import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

 public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000); 

}


}
```